# async react-select with defaultValue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

So I have a `state` of dynamically loaded options(API call):

```
// myOptions will be loaded with data after API call returned
// and will re-render the component using `useEffect`
const [myOptions, setMyOptions] = useState()
```

I'm loading `react-select` like so and everything works fine, except the `defaultValue`:

```
<AsyncCreatableSelect
  defaultValue={myOptions?.[0]}
  defaultOptions={myOptions}
  onChange={selectHandler}
  isMulti
  isSearchable
/>
```

The `myOptions?.[0]` is just an example. I want it to be passed with props, but the point here is that it simply doesn't work this way. It will work however if I'll pass the object right away when the component is loaded at the first time, like so:

```
<AsyncCreatableSelect
  defaultValue={
    {
      _id: "myLongId",
      value: "Some Value",
      label: "someLabel",
    },
  }
  defaultOptions={myOptions}
  onChange={selectHandler}
  isMulti
  isSearchable
/>
```

But obviously I don't want to hardcore it, but use it dynamically with returned data from the API call and passed props.

Also, the `myOptions?.[0]`(when fulfilled) and the object (`{_id: "myLongId", value: "Some Value",label: "someLabel",}`) are exactly the same, meaning they're `===` to `true`. So the only reason for it not to work is some kind of memoization at the end of react-select. This is crazy... it should be triggered on the prop change.

I'm sure I'm not the only one dealing with this, can you share your solution to this please?

Thanks.

Comment: create new state "const [defValue, setdefValue] = useState({})", and then update using effect. assign this to "defaulValue" attribute.

Comment: @Immanuel that's literally what I did. It doesn't trigger if it's dynamic

Comment: for defaultValue, in your statement its mentioned as its sent thru props. for defaultOptions you have that, even for defaultValue have you done the same?

Comment: @Immanuel Oh shit man, u're right, I didn't post about it, but I indeed tried that out. It doesn't work. Also, the basis is the same(props or state), as it will re-render the component with the useEffect in place. But that doesn't re-render the react-select for some reason, as it has some kind of memoization in place.